# Maven - Custom output project structure

Tags: maven, module, project, structure

Good evening, people.
I've already wasted the whole day trying to manage with maven.

I have the following project structure:

```
base-pom.xml
 |-module1
 |  |-module1-resources
 |-module2
 |  |-module2-resources
 |-module3
 |  |module3-resources
 |
 |-general-resources
```

I'm looking for some way of getting the following output structure:

```
output-folder
 |-libs-folder/3rdrarty-jars
 |-config-folder/general-resources not-packed
 |-module1.jar
 |-module2.jar
 |-module3.jar
 |-module1-resources not-packed
 |-module2-resources not-packed
 |-module3-resources not-packed
```

Also a thing to mention: classpath of my project modules should be something like this:

*Class-Path: /config-folder module2.jar module3.jar libs/3rdparty_1.jar libs/3rdparty_2.jar libs/3rdparty_3.jar*

I don't know if maven allows to have such a complicated output structure - all samples, i've found having wasted a lot of time, show nothing even similar to my requirements.